# Micronaut JWT attribute settings being ignored

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, jwt, micronaut, samesite

I have a Micronaut-based web-app and I have been having some issues on the authentication side. The problem is specifically related to the change browsers are undergoing where SameSite defaults to Lax and if you use SameSite: none then the cookie must be secure. I am using all of the latest stable versions, e.g. Micronaut 2.0.1.

Chrome gives me the following exception:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at
> http://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute.
> It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with
> cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.
> You can review cookies in developer tools under
> Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

The one confusing thing is that it mentions http and not https although all the URLs are https when I watch the Network activity. In particular, it complains about two requests and both requester URLs are https.

When I try log in, the authentication happens and the JWT cookie is returned but then I get the error. I can see the details of the JWT as follows:

> Set-Cookie: JWT=eyJhbGciOiJub2...U5ODYxNzA2MX0.; Max-Age=3600; Expires=Fri, 28 Aug 2020 13:17:41 GMT; Path=/; HTTPOnly

The cookie is neither "secure", nor is SameSite specified (hence it defaulting to Lax). I require it to be both "SameSite: None" and "secure".

I have Micronaut security configured differently in different environments because we use OpenId (Azure AD) in our production environment and we just use internal authentication in our testing environments. We seem to have this same ignored config issue in both environments. Here are the two YMLs:

```
  application:
    name: xxxxx
  security:
    authentication: idtoken
    oauth2:
      enabled: true
      clients:
        azure:
          client-id: ${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
          client-secret: ${OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}
          openid:
            issuer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx
      callback-uri: ${OAUTH_CALLBACK_URI}
    redirect:
      login-success: ${LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL}
      logout: '/logout-handler/logout-success'
    endpoints:
      logout:
        get-allowed: true
    token:
      jwt:
        cookie:
          cookie-same-site: none
          cookie-secure: true
```

and

```
  application:
    name: xxxxx
  security:
    authentication: cookie
    oauth2:
      enabled: false
      clients:
        azure:
          client-id: ${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
          client-secret: ${OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}
          openid:
            issuer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx
      callback-uri: ${OAUTH_CALLBACK_URI}
    redirect:
      login-success: ${LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL}
      logout: '/logout-handler/logout-success'
    endpoints:
      logout:
        get-allowed: true
    token:
      jwt:
        cookie:
          cookie-same-site: none
          cookie-secure: true
```

As you can see, I am trying to set cookie-same-site to none and cookie-secure to true for both. It doesn't seem to be working. For that matter, according to the docs, cookie-secure should default to true so I am even more confused as to why this is not pulling through.

I assume the problem is either (1) something I am misunderstanding in the config or (2) a bug in Micronaut. If anyone could advise, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but the value needs to be `cookie-same-site: 'None'`